# mod_rewrite URL (condition in second part)

Tags: regex, apache, url, mod-rewrite

I have the following Rewrite Rule

```
RewriteRule ^/product/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/((test_data|data_test)/)?([^/]*)$ /product/?query_one=$1&query_two=$2&query_three=$3&query_four=$4&file_path=$6/$7
```

In last `file_path`'s value I am combining `$6/$7`.

Is it possible if `$6` has no value then `file_path` will only be `$7`? I don't want `/` id `$6` is None. In simple I want to put condition in this part.

**Edit**

> https://example.com/product/one/two/three/four/test_data/file.jar

TO

> https://example.com/product/?query_one=one&query_two=two&query_three=three&query_four=four&file_path=test_data/file.jar

Problem is with this URL

> https://example.com/product/one/two/three/four/test_file.xml

Please suggest?

Thanks!

Comment: Pls provide some examples of your source and target URLs.

Comment: @anubhava question updated with examples

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to simplify your matching pattern a bit. Following works for me:

```
RewriteRule ^/?product/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(.*?)/?$ /product/?query_one=$1&query_two=$2&query_three=$3&query_four=$4&file_path=$5 [L,QSA,NC]
```

OR if you want to make sure that dir is only `(test_data|data_test)`then use:

```
RewriteRule ^/?product/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/((?:(?:test_data|data_test)/)?.*?)/?$ /product/?query_one=$1&query_two=$2&query_three=$3&query_four=$4&file_path=$5 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: No, I want to work this pattern for both type of URLs. I don't want `/` in `file_type` value if `$6` is empty.

Comment: I never post a solution unless I try it out myself :P In other words yes above works for both of your URLs.

Comment: In this case anything can come `(.*?)` but I want to give only two options `(test_data|data_test)/`

Comment: but `(test_data|data_test)` doesn't come before `test_file.xml`

Comment: Stepping away for 30 mins.

Comment: `(test_data|data_test)` is optional. It is required for `.jar` case but not for `xml` case.